# SQL Server Job Schedule Not Running - no error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, windows-server-2016

I have been trying to figure this out for days now.

I have an SSIS package deployed to the IS Catalogues and a SQL Server Agent job to run it.

It works fine when I right click and start job at step, however when I try to run on schedule it just doesn't run. No error message, nothing.

I have been doing some research, and it seems to be a permissions thing.

I understand I need to create a Credential from a user (login?) who has appropriate permissions, then create a proxy from that credential, then run the job as the proxy, however this does not seem to work.

I have even tried creating the user / credential / proxy from the windows admin account but no joy. I am fairly certain that running a job as a windows admin would be a no no.

One thing to note is that the server is not on a domain. I need to create the credential using TSQL as the elipsis on New Credential seems to require one.

Can someone please let me know what the best way would be to set up a user / login / credential / proxy / job etc to run an SSIS package which is scheduled on a SQL Server which is NOT on a domain?

In particular what are the appropriate permissions. The jobs in question are logging on to the local machine and a remote server (connection string in a config file) and moving data around only. Nothing more.

It seems like it would be a simple thing...

Comment: If the job runs when you right click it, and doesn't under the schedule then you've set the credentials right, sounds like you set the schedule up incorrectly. If it's not running, then it's not part of the schedule, or the step is being reached, possibly because a step is set to end the job earlier.

Comment: Hi - there is only one step in the job. At the moment the only schedule I have set up is to test the scheduling works - a one time event set to go 2 minutes after I click OK. Is there a minimum time between clicking OK and having a job run?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out...

Stupid error on my part. There is a tickbox in the scheduler (Enabled) which was unticked. I am not sure why MS unticks this every time a job runs once but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

it could be timezone difference issue..where your server is running in CST but your are setting scheduler based on IST time. you need to check corresponding CST Time of scheduler IST.